# Requisição cross-origin bloqueada ao criar uma box

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react, cors

Ola estou iniciando no React e me deparei com um problema, estou tentando fazer um app parecido com dropbox, na tela principal você cria uma box e pode fazer upload de arquivos, porem quando clico em criar aparece esta mensagem:

> "Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em https://app-reactteste.herokuapp.com/boxes. (Motivo: o cabeçalho CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' não está presente)."

Vi que existe uma extensão CORS para o navegador, ativei e aparece **error 503**, gostaria de saber se isso é normalmente um erro no código mesmo?

O back-end esta no github: https://github.com/onz3/backend

Comment: Está passando header na requisição feita pelo front?

Answer (score 1):

Possivelmente o seu problema está no backend. Adicione a biblioteca [do Cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors). No caso ele é um middleware. A configuração é bem simples conforme a documentação.

```js
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

Comment: Ah sim é que ja esta certinho isso:
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");

mas continua com o mesmo erro 
const app = express();  
app.use(cors());